# How to read from a text file, which is simulatenously getting written to? - JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, file-handling

I have two Java Files, which is the server and the client. The server executes, a command sent from client, in the server and logs the output to a text file. Now the client tries to read from the same text file to display the result in the client, simultaneously while the server is executing the program.

**What I have done:**
I have created two server sockets - One to read from the file and One to execute the command.
I have two clients, one client socket to write the command to the server and the other to read from the server.

**Problem Facing:** Concurrency issues(My Guess)
This is the error I'm facing.

```
Waiting for client on port 9090...
Just connected to /127.0.0.1:64057
MIX1 is reading the data from the port /127.0.0.1:64057
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Waiting for client on port 9090...

at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:401)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
at readserver.ReadServer.main(ReadServer.java:63)
```

Comment: This is a network problem, not a problem with using the file. Also, the results of reading from a file which you write into at the same time is undefined, so try to avoid it...

Comment: I just came back; I went away as this error is quite unclear: it seems there is one File 'file.txt' on the file system, a java server application writing to the file and a client application reading from the file. And then there is that socket problem. The last problem seems to be a not closed soket or such. You need to explain it a bit more, still being concise.

Comment: What is a network problem? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to bind to the same port.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Means that you are trying to bind to an port that is already used.

Comment: That is not the error due to which execution stopped, it is

     java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
      java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Answer (score 0):

Reading from file, in which another thread or process is writing at this moment, is not the best possible implementation. It may easily lead to not consistent data or to some loss of data as well. Try to avoid it with semaphores or some other kind of mechanisms to avoid those situations.

As the others already mentioned, the exception that you've shown is because of network problems.